How to run a task in background in react native and play sound
I have a React Native app that needs to fetch data and play a sound every 15 minutes, regardless of whether the app is in the background or foreground. However, I am experiencing an issue: when the app goes into the background, it doesn't play the sound after 15 minutes. The sound only plays when I reopen the app.
Here is the code I am using:
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      StyleSheet,
      ScrollView,
      View,
      Text,
      FlatList,
      StatusBar,
      ListRenderItem,
    } from 'react-native';
    import {Header, Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
    import BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch';
    import {Button} from '@rneui/base';
    import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
    
    // Define the type for event
    interface Event {
      taskId: string;
      timestamp: string;
    }
    const getTime = () => {
      let currentDate = new Date();
    
      // Get the current hours, minutes, and seconds
      let hours = currentDate.getHours();
      let minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
      let seconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
    
      // Format the time as HH:MM:SS
      let currentTime = `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
    
      return currentTime;
    };
    
    const App: React.FC = () => {
      const [events, setEvents] = useState<Event[]>([]);
      const [data, setData] = useState<any>(getTime());
    
      useEffect(() => {
        initBackgroundFetch();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, []);
    
      const addEvent = useCallback(async (taskId: string): Promise<void> => {
        console.log('Hello from a background task', getTime());
        setEvents(prevEvents => [
          ...prevEvents,
          {
            taskId: taskId,
            timestamp: getTime(),
          },
        ]);
      }, []);
    
      const initBackgroundFetch = async () => {
        const onEvent = async (taskId: string) => {
          console.log('started task time', getTime());
          await addEvent(taskId);
          BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
          console.log('finished task time', getTime());
          triggerBackgroundFetch();
        };
    
        const onTimeout = async (taskId: string) => {
          console.warn('[BackgroundFetch] TIMEOUT task: ', taskId);
          BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
        };
    
        let status = await BackgroundFetch.configure(
          {
            minimumFetchInterval: 15, // <-- minutes (15 is minimum allowed)
            forceAlarmManager: false, // Set true to bypass JobScheduler.
            stopOnTerminate: false,
            startOnBoot: true,
          },
          onEvent,
          onTimeout,
        );
    
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] configure status: ', status);
      };
    
      const renderItem: ListRenderItem<Event> = ({item}) => (
        <Text>
          [{item.taskId}]: {item.timestamp}
        </Text>
      );
      const triggerBackgroundFetch = async () => {
        setData(Math.random() * 50);
        var whoosh = new Sound('sound.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
          if (error) {
            console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
            return;
          }
    
          // Play the sound with an onEnd callback
          whoosh.play(success => {
            if (success) {
              console.log('successfully finished playing');
            } else {
              console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
            }
          });
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <SafeAreaView>
            <ScrollView
              contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
              style={styles.scrollView}>
              <Header />
              <View style={styles.body}>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>BackgroundFetch Demo</Text>
                  <View>
                    <Text>random:{data}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <Button onPress={triggerBackgroundFetch}>Call API</Button>
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <FlatList
                data={events}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.timestamp}
              />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      scrollView: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
      },
      body: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      },
      sectionContainer: {
        marginTop: 32,
        paddingHorizontal: 24,
      },
      sectionTitle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: Colors.black,
      },
      sectionDescription: {
        marginTop: 8,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: Colors.dark,
      },
    });
    
    export default App;

